# Devise not logging in after new custom action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi I'm fairly new to rails and am having trouble trying to add a new post method.

I would like to create a new method that enables a user.

So I have modified my User controller to have the following method

```
def enable

if (!@user.enabled)
  @user.enabled = true;
  if @user.save
    UserMailer.send_enabled_message(@user).deliver
    redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully enabled.'
  else
    redirect_to users_url, notice: 'Could not enable user.'
  end
else
redirect_to users_url, notice: 'Could not enable user.'
end
```

end

And I have added the following to my routes:

```
match 'users/:id' => 'users#enable', :via => 'post', :action => :enable
```

And added the following to my view displaying a table of users:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Enable', user, method: :enable, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

And this all seems to work but i think my route has overwritten my login post as I am unable to login any more. Do I need to create a new form or can I do a quick submit like this?

Also along the same lines when you are using a link_to how can I do something like: `<%= link_to 'enable', enable_user(user) %>` how/where do i need to create the `enable_user` method?

Thanks GoGoCarl got it working now. Had to change my routes to this:

```
resources :users do
    post 'enable', on: :member
end
```

and my view to this:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Enable', enable_user_path(user), method: :enable, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your questions can be answered by simply changing your route definition in routes.rb.  Remove the line you added, and under where you presumably have:

```
resources :users
```

Change it to:

```
resources :users do
  post 'enable', :on => :collection
end
```

This adds a handler at the resource level for the collection (so, /users) as opposed to a member (/users/2).  It automatically gets handled by the "enable" method in your users controller.

So, first answer -- yes, you are matching all URLs that post to user, so that does indeed override the login POST.  Defining as above will route things the way you want.

Second answer, how do you get the URL?  Well, now that it's routed this way, you can run rake routes to see what the defined path is.  For now, I'll spare you the trouble:

```
enable_users_path
```

So you can do:

```
link_to 'enable', enable_users_path
```

Again, by defining the route in the way above, this path method is generated for you.  You could have also defined this method via an attribute, if you ever run into this down the line.

So, if you make the change above, you should:

1. Be able to get your login back (as well as any other POST method to users)
2. Have a method enable_users_path to get the URL
3. Be able to post to /users/enable

That should get you going.  For more information on routing:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html